# withLatestFrom not working inside switchMap

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I am new to RxJs. Can someone help me understand why `withLatestFrom` is freezing when I wrap it inside a `switchMap` ?

```
withLatestFromNoCancel() {
    const hi$ = of("hi");
    const click$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById("click1"), "click");

    const example = click$.pipe(withLatestFrom(click$, hi$));
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
withLatestFromStrangeWithSwitchMap() {
    const hi$ = of("hi");
    const click$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById("click1"), "click");

    const example = click$.pipe(
      switchMap(e => of(e).pipe(withLatestFrom(click$, hi$))),
    );
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`withLatestFrom` emits only when its source Observable emits. In your case it's `of(e)` that emits just once and then completes so it never reacts to `click$`, `hi$`.

So it's not because of `switchMap`. That's how `withLatestFrom` works.

Comment: Have a look at examples here https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom